# Error message when exporting plot as XLS file

Tags: export, numerics, warning-messages, distributions

I imported data from excel which has 300 data (which are change in CDS spread). I want to compute corresponding CDF for the data using kernel density estimation. I get the CDF plot but cannt get the data back in excel and getting following error. Can anybody help in resolving error please

```
citi = Import["CorrelD.xlsx", {"Data", "data", All, 1}]
d = SmoothKernelDistribution[citi]
citicdf = Table[Plot[f[d, x], {x, -85, 60}, PlotLabel -> f], {f, {CDF}}]
Export["test5.xls", citicdf,  "XLS"])
```

The error I get is

```
Export::fmterr: "Invalid \!\(\"XLS\"\) format. "
```

Comment: It's not possible to export graphics to XLS.  You can copy and paste the graphic to Excel if you like, but Export doesn't support graphics with XLS.

Comment: If you really need to work *in* Excel then you should into ExcelLink for Mathematica. I think it only works with 32bit Excel though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer -- I just can't refrain from commenting on your coding style. Your expression

```
Table[Plot[f[d, x], {x, -85, 60}, PlotLabel -> f], {f, {CDF}}]
```

is valid, but it amazes me. I would never have thought of it. Because I am extremely simple-minded, I would have written

```
{Plot[CDF[d, x], {x, -85, 60}, PlotLabel -> CDF]}
```

Comment: Congrats on the accept, @m_goldberg! :)

Comment: @kale. Apparently, Kausik is a good sport with a fine, ironic sense of humor. I admire that.